# Can I dump the source of a live Chromium window to a string?

Tags: bash, chromium, xdotool

I'm using xdotool to open a Chromium browser and click a few things , but I'm wondering if I can get the source code of the live window it's using and dump it into a string to check if the source contains a particular string.

I know a `wget` can get me the source of a window , but what I want is the window that's already open as it will contain the string I want, but the `wget` option may not.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If ctrl+U (show source) can be used, it will save your time, but if you need to inspect live HTML, try this xdotool script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdotool
search --sync --onlyvisible --name chrome
windowactivate --sync
key Ctrl+Shift+C
sleep 0.5
key Down
sleep 0.5
key ctrl+F
sleep 1
type "What you try to find"
key Return
```

Save as 'xdotool_script', then run it like you executing bash script

```
$ chmod +x xdotool_script
$ ./xdotool_script`
```

Comment: Thanks , thats kind of what i want , but i also want to get the result (even the whole or part of the source) into a variable that i can then use later ... is that possible ?

Comment: If you want to process data on the page, I will suggest using extension, Like [Chrome Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).